# excel sheet reads 13.40.pm but vba reads 0.569444

Tags: vba, excel

Excel sheet reads 13.40 PM but vba reads 0.569444

in cell B4 we have 13.40 PM  exactly as it was entered, my code to compare this with current time and see if we are late

```
'sh is a variable pointing at my sheet
'dt is a date  type

dtstart = TimeValue(sh.Range("B" & r.row).Value)
dbInterval = dtOff - Time
```

I get a type mismatch error from timevalue() because I believe it expects a string.
`Cstr(mycell)` doesn't help
This number does not look like anything logical to me.
I am stuck with the data already in the sheet, placed there by another script
Anyone?

Comment: Excel stores date & time as floating point values. `13:40` happens to be 820 minutes into a 1440-minute day, which works out to 0.569444

Comment: Try some variant of TimeValue(Format(sh.Range("B" & r.row).Value),"hh:mm") ...  IOW, use Format to return a formatted string and use TimeValue on that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments `0.569444` is **already** the `TimeValue`. You can omit all of the other code and just do this:

```
dtstart = Range("B" & r.row).Value
```

Date types are stored internally in both Excel and VBA as a `Double`.  They can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the TimeValue in Cell B4, then use following line:

```
dtstart = TimeValue(Format(sh.Range("B" & r.Row).Value, "hh:mm"))
```

For debug purpose, use the line below :

```
Debug.Print dtstart
```

The result in immediate window is `13:40:00`

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado you're a superstar

Comment: Why would you format a Date value to a String and then use TimeValue to convert it back to Date? This is the equivalent  to something like `CDate(CStr(CDate()))`.

Comment: @ Comintern what will you do in case the cell contains a full date with the time, like 18/09/2016 13:40:00 and you want to extract just the time ?

Comment: You subtract the integer portion.